# Cross-compiled exe slow on some windows machines

Tags: windows, gcc, mingw, cross-compiling, can-bus

I have a library which is cross-compiled inside Ubuntu with MinGW 7, GCC 9.3.0 for Windows.

The purpose of the library is to provide a CAN protocol over PCANBasic (CAN driver for Windows).

I call these library functions inside a C# .Net Framework 4.6 WPF Application.

Everything works but on some Windows 10 machines, the program's CAN communication is extremely slow. But these machines do have more CPU power (quad core instead of dual-core or more GHz). All use the same PCAN USB driver library.

I am not a professional Windows developer nor a .Net Developer so I only have some unanswered questions.

- Can there be missing OP-Code for the CPU?
- Could there be something running in compatibility mode?
- Can I somehow analyze the USB load like on Linux?

Sorry for the may broad question but I am a little bit lost what to do.

Comment: Probably not missing OP code as that would usually crash the application. Have you tried disabling antivirus? Also make sure you looked at the usual suspects of Windows slowness. One of them is the temp file (open Explorer and type `%TEMP%` in the address bar) does not contain thousands of files.

Comment: This is often related to the driver. Microsoft's cancerous updates tend to overwrite working drivers with broken drivers - but Microsoft are just aimlessly updating drivers without a clue about what they are doing, so you'll have to chase down whoever made the driver and have them publish a correct one.